# Wordpress custom post type with custom taxonomy slug

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I created custom post type with custom taxonomy. Its working, but i am facing one issue is

http://example.com/taxonomy-slug/%term%/post-title this is my custom post type url

exg:

http://example.com/boat-hire/party-boats/bmw-z4

Here

boat-hire -> taxonomy-slug

party-boats -> taxonomy-term

bmw-z4 -> product title

custom-post-type slug -> products/%custom_taxonomy%

this link is working, but also its working when i change taxonomy term value

Exg: http://example.com/boat-hire/paty-bts/bmw-z4

This link also working even after changing(party-boats -> paty-bts) or put any value at that position. Actually it should be redirect to page not found page.

I have listed my code below

**Custom Post Type:**

```html
<?php
function create_boat_posttype() {
    $supports = array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail',
        'excerpt',
        // 'custom-fields',
        // 'revisions'
    );
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Boats', 'plural'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Boat', 'singular'),
        'menu_name' => _x('Boats', 'admin menu'),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x('Boat', 'admin bar'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add Boat', 'add new'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Boat'),
        'new_item' => __('New Boat'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Boat'),
        'view_item' => __('View Boat'),
        'all_items' => __('All Boats'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Boat'),
        'not_found' => __('No boats found.'),
    );    
    $args = array(
        'supports' => $supports,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => 'my_boat_hire',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'boat-hire/%boat_term%','with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'boat_term' ),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
    );
    register_post_type('boat', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_boat_posttype' );
```

**Custom Taxonomy:**

```html
add_action( 'init', 'create_boat_taxonomies', 0 );
if(!function_exists('create_boat_taxonomies'))
{
function create_boat_taxonomies() {
$labels = array(
'name' => __('Boat Categories'),
'singular_name' => __('Boat Category'),
'search_items' => __('Search Boat Categories'),
'all_items' => __('All Boat Categories'),
'parent_item' => __('Parent'),
'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent:'),
'edit_item' => __('Edit Boat Category'),
'update_item' => __('Update Boat Category'),
'add_new_item' => __('Add New Boat Category'),
'new_item_name' => __('New Boat Category'),
'menu_name' => __('Boat Categories'),
);
$args = array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'query_var' => 'boat_category',
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'boat-hire',
'with_front' => false ),
);
register_taxonomy( 'boat_term', array( 'boat' ), $args );
}
}

function filter_boat_type_link($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'boat')
        return $link;
 
    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'boat_term'))
        $link = str_replace('%boat_term%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_boat_type_link', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Please post your custom post type and taxonomy declaration

Comment: I have updated my post with codes here. Please check.